# org-mode re-read header configuration

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I create a new org-mode file, I create a header similar to this:

```
#+TITLE:      Some title
#+AUTHOR:     Me
#+CATEGORY:   things
#+STARTUP:    align fold nodlcheck oddeven lognotestate
#+OPTIONS:    H:4 num:nil toc:t \n:nil @:t ::t |:t ^:{} -:t f:t *:t
#+OPTIONS:    skip:nil d:(HIDE) tags:not-in-toc
#+LANGUAGE:   en
#+PROPERTY:   header-args :results code :exports both :noweb yes
```

However, when I specify the `#+PROPERTY` setting, it doesn't take effect until I reopen the file.

How can I force org-mode to re-read header configuration without closing the buffer and reopening it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do a `M-x revert-buffer`. This is, in short, a „re-open file from disk” macro.

Comment: Did you trying hitting C-c C-c on any of your #+ line ?